# How to achieve vertical alignmernt of text paragraphs between Bootstrap columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using quite a standard responsive Bootstrap grid.

The task that is puzzling me: in a row, I have multiple columns.
Each column has a caption, maybe an image, and some variable-lenght text.
The text (and only the text) should have a background color, according to the design.

Also by design, the bottoms of all the colored areas should be aligned (i.e. at the same vertical level). The designer suggests to achieve it by adding "colored padding" to the texts, till they reach the lowest level needed.

I tried to build a small example illustrating it, it's here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xgrnqxpr/2/

Code from the sample:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">


        <div class="span3">
          <h3>
          TEXT1
          </h3>
          <div class="g_class">
            <p>
              Short text
              Short text
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <h3>
            TEXT2
          </h3>
          <div class="r_class">
            <p>
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long textLong text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
              Long text
            </p>
          </div>



    </div>
</div>
```

(you may need to enlarge the visible area, to see the column structure).
Apparently, the "green" area is shorter than the red. By design, I would need to expand the green part - till the bottom of the red one.

Any hint how to achieve it in CSS?

Thanks for care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using flex: http://jsfiddle.net/xgrnqxpr/3/

No changes are made to the html. Only the css changes, as shown below.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.span3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.span3 h3 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.span3 div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.r_class {
  background-color: red;
}

.g_class {
  background-color: green;
}
```

The css change is made with two goals:

1. the `display: flex;` on `.row` is used to make sure that every cell has the same height through the use of `align-items: stretch;`
2. the `display: flex;` on `.span3` and the assignation of the `flex` property to its children is done to ensure that the caption wont move and the text will take all additional space.

If you want to play with it a bit more and for more explanation on how the flex (and flex related) properties work, I think this can be a good source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/